# Attribute based webapi2 routing returns 404 for some methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I'm presently working on a project that has been upgraded to Webapi2 from Webapi. Part of the conversion includes the switch to using attribute based routing.

I've appropriately setup my routes in the Global.asax (as follows)

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes());
```

and removed the previous routing configuration.

I have decorated all of my API controllers with the appropriate **System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute** and **System.Web.Http.RoutePrefixAttribute** attributes.

If I inspect **System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes** with the debugger I can see that all my expected routes are registered in the collection. Likewise the appropriate routes are available within the included generated [Webapi Help Page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages) documentation as expected.

Even though all appears to be setup properly a good number of my REST calls result in a 404 not found response from the server.

I've found some notable similarities specific to GET methods (this is all I've tested so far)

- If a method accepts 0 parameters it **will** fail
- If a route overrides the prefix it **will** fail
- If a method takes a string parameter it is **likely** to succeed
- return type seems to have no affect
- Naming a route seems to have no affect
- Ordering a route seems to have no affect
- Renaming the underlying method seems to have no affect

Worth noting is that my API controllers appear in a separate area, but given that some routes do work I don't expect this to be the issue at hand.

Example of non-functional method call

```
[RoutePrefix("api/postman")]
public class PostmanApiController : ApiController
{
    ...
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("all", Name = "GetPostmanCollection")]
    [ResponseType(typeof (PostmanCollectionGet))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPostmanCollection()
    {
        return Ok(...);
    }
    ...
}
```

I expect this to be available via **`http://[application-root]/api/postman/all`**

Interestingly enough a call to

```
Url.Link("GetPostmanCollection", null)
```

will return the above expected url

A very similar example of method calls within the same controller where some work and some do not.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/machine")]
public class MachineApiController : ApiController
{
    ...
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("byowner/{owner}", Name = "GetPostmanCollection")]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetByOwner([FromUri] string owner)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/api/oses/{osType}")]
    public IEnumerable<OsAndVersionGet> GetOSes([FromUri] string osType)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Where a call to **`http://[application-root]/api/machineby/ownername`**  succeeds and **`http://[application-root]/api/oses/osType`** does not.

I've been poking at this far too long, any idea as to what the issue may be?

Comment: When you call /api/oses/osType it didn't find a controller or method in a controller?

Comment: A call to it results in a 404 not found message, but from the Webapi Help Page it appears to know which controller & method to resolve to.

Comment: Did MapHttpAttributeRoutes method called before any mvc routing registration?

Comment: @mt_serg that was the issue. I was mapping my MVC routes before mapping my WebApi routes, swapping the order seems to have fixed my issue. If you wish to respond with an answer I'd be happy to give you credit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check that you configure your HttpConfiguration via the [`MapHttpAttributeRoutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479134%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method before *any* ASP.NET MVC routing registration.

In accordance to Microsoft's CodePlex entry on [Attribute Routing in MVC and Web API](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Attribute%20Routing%20in%20MVC%20and%20Web%20API) the **Design** section states:

> In most cases, MapHttpAttributeRoutes or MapMvcAttributeRoutes will be
>   called first so that attribute routes are registered before the global
>   routes (and therefore get a chance to supersede global routes).
>   Requests to attribute routed controllers would also be filtered to
>   only those that originated from an attribute route.

Therefore, within the `Global.asax` (or where registering routes) it is appropriate to call:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(c => c.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()); // http routes
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(...); // mvc routes
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the correct answer and can cause headache down the line if WebApi is configured as such. WebApi MUST be configured on its own HttpConfiguration, NOT on the GlobalConfiguration. Search in SO for more topics on this subject.

Comment: @MoonStom: You are not correct. Globalconfiguration.Configure() passes the appropriate HttpConfiguration for WebApi into the callback. The important part is that MapHttpAttributeRoutes() must called before any MapRoute() or MapHttpRoute() calls.

Comment: @MoonStom: it depends. With System.Web pipeline (HttpContext), GlobalConfiguration is used. With Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb pipeline (OwinContext), it is true a new HttpConfiguration is  recommended.

Answer (score 9):

In my case it was a stupid mistake, I am posting this so people behind me making the same mistake may read this before they check everything else at quantum level.

My mistake was, my controller's name did not end with the word `Controller`.

Happy new year

Comment: thanks, this answer saved my buns - the file was appropriately suffixed with Controller, but I must have forgot to suffix the *class* name with Controller when I copied the controller from a previous version.  FACEPALM.